# Relative path to image file not found when approached from another URL

Tags: asp.net, iis

In IIS I have 2 Sites: Default and SiteA (bound to a different port)
SiteA (ASP.Net) works correct when approached on the other port (http://myurl:99). The Default site contains a link to SiteA: (http://myurl/SiteA). When the page is opened via the link on the Default site, the icons are missing.

In the .cshtml file it says

```
<td><img class="statusicon" src="@item.StatusIcon" /></td>
```

Where `item.StatusIcon` contains a relative path, e.g.: `.\\Images\\Running.png`. Obviously when loading the page via the link on the Default site, the current directory is pointing to `D:\sites\default`, while the current directory is `D:\sites\SiteA\Website` when approached via port 99.

I can copy the Images folder from `D:\sites\SiteA\Website` to `D:\sites\default`. Then it works, but I don't think that is a good solution. What is a better solution so I don't get duplicate icons?

Can I change some setting in IIS, or is there a way to create the path dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the URL in the code should be resolved to a correct URL. I made two changes to my code to make that work.

I changed the relative path of the image from

`.\\Images\\Running.png`

to

`~/Images/Running.png`

I guess using file-paths isn't a good practice on webpages.

And in the .cshtml file I changed the line

```
<td><img class="statusicon" src="@item.StatusIcon" /></td>
```

to

```
<td><img class="statusicon" src=@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(@item.StatusIcon) /></td>
```

to resolve the URL to a correct path and be independent of which URL is used to reach the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the url of image to replace physical path.

```
<img class="statusicon" src="http://myurl.com:801/sierra2.jpg" />
```

[image]

If you insist on using physical path, let's assume that your application has the function of uploading images and setting model.StatusIcon to path.
When uploading a image and saving it, you can set path as absolute path.

```
String path="D:\sites\SiteA\Website\"+file.FileName,
Model.StatusIcon=path;
```

Then `@item.StatusIcon` is `D:\sites\SiteA\Website\imagename`.

I recommend you to use url as src, because it is simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't think the solution is in setting an absolute path. I think somewhere in the settings a path is pointing to the wrong folder. If I copy the icons to D:\sites\default\Images, it works. Why is the server looking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Relative path will be affected by the physical root path of domain.